# How AES/GCM deals with data smaller than block size?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

I am using [bouncy castle library](https://bouncycastle.org/) for encryption and decryption in c# and I was wondering how to deal with plain text smaller than block size?

here is what I have done so far:

```
AesFastEngine engine = new AesFastEngine();
GcmBlockCipher cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(engine);
AeadParameters param = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameters(key), 128, iv, null);
cipher.Init(true, parameters);

byte[] encData = new byte[plain.Length];
cipher.ProcessBytes(plain, 0, plain.Length, encData, 0);
```

when the plain data is smaller then block size it does nothing.

Comment: You have to call `doFinal(..)` on the last data block you process.

Comment: AES/GCM does not need padding, it uses CTR (counter) mode. As @Robert states you do need to call `doFinal()`, that is needed to generate the auth tag.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Bouncy Castle and Oracle / Java implementations are not *online*. That is, the online properties of the underlying CTR mode encryption aren't kept. Online in this context means that bytes are directly encrypted/decrypted when they arive. This may have to do with how the encryption is handled and how the authentication tags are handled.

AES-CTR can be implemented in multiple ways. You can either first encrypt the counter and then directly XOR with plaintext/ciphertext when it arrives. You can also first buffer the plaintext and then, once you have a full block, create the counter, encrypt it and then XOR a full block of plaintext. This had advantages in the sense that it more closely resembles other modes of operation such as CBC. Furthermore you may not have to buffer the key stream in memory all that time.

The authentication tag can also be handled differently. Here there are basically three options. You could simply regard the authentication tag as a separate entity to the ciphertext. This lets you keep the online properties of CTR mode and should, in my opinion, be the preferred option. You could also see it as part of the ciphertext, but in that case you lose the online properties *during decryption*; you would need to know where the ciphertext ends before you can handle the last number of bytes that make up the authentication tag. So you'd need to buffer at least the size in bytes of the authentication tag. Finally, still during decryption, you might only want to return plaintext bytes *after verification* of the plaintext bytes. In that case you'd need to buffer the entire ciphertext and return the plaintext in one go.

As the authentication tag issues are only for decryption it is likely that Bouncy will just buffer because of the way CTR is implemented. You'd indeed have to call `doFinal` - as Robert already mentioned in the comments - to retrieve the last block of ciphertext as well as the authentication tag. It could be that the encryption is not yet performed because the encryption routine is kept somewhat symmetrical to the decryption routine as well.